# Выравнивание window.open() окна по центру монитора

Tags: javascript

Открываю на сайте всплывающее окно, токо оно открывается в левом верхнем углу. 
window.open("site.ru", "", "width=1050,height=800");

Как сделать так что бы всплывающее окно отображалось по центру монитора?

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно определить значение top и left в третьем аргументе.Параметры top и left определяют отступы сверху(top) и слева(left).
Пример кода:

```
window.open("example.com","","top=100,left=100,width=1050,height=800");
```

Comment: Решение нашел такое:

    var x = screen.width/2 - 1050/2;
    var y = screen.height/2 - 800/2;
    window.open('сайт.ру', '<?=$sh_id?>','width=1050,height=800,left='+x+',top='+y);

Answer (score 1):

Для позиционирования окна, открываемого при помощи `window.open` существуют параметры `top` и `left`:

```
window.open("site.ru", "", "width=800,height=600,top=200,left=300");
```

А вот как посчитать эти top и left в общем случае это большой вопрос.

Если монитор один или Вас устраивает что в многомониторном окружении позиционироваие будет работать криво - то все относительно просто.

Если же Вы ищете универсальное решение, поищите его  [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068373/center-a-popup-window-on-screen)

Comment: Решение нашел такое:

    var x = screen.width/2 - 1050/2;
    var y = screen.height/2 - 800/2;
    window.open('сайт.ру', '<?=$sh_id?>','width=1050,height=800,left='+x+',top='+y);

Comment: @Игорь вот оно для 1 монитора

Comment: не понял о чем вы

Answer (score 1):

Решение нашел такое:

```
var x = screen.width/2 - 1050/2;
var y = screen.height/2 - 800/2;
window.open('сайт.ру', '<?=$sh_id?>','width=1050,height=800,left='+x+',top='+y);
```